# Inserting a block with .NET is not using the files search paths to locate the files

Tags: c#, .net, autocad-plugin

I have two blocks defined in this folder:

**D:\My Documents\My AutoCAD\Blocks**

The blocks are:

- COORD_CROSS.DWG
- COORD2D.DWG

In Autocad, the **files search path** is set thus:

[image: Files Search Path]

[image: Blocks]

If I start a new drawing and insert one of these blocks by just typing their name, it is found and inserted.

Yet, I find that with .NET I have to prefix the path. Eg:

```
if (!acBlkTbl.Has("COORD2D"))
{
    _AcDb.Database blkDb = new _AcDb.Database(false, true);
    blkDb.ReadDwgFile("D:\\My Documents\\My AutoCAD\\Blocks\\COORD2D" + ".DWG", 
                     System.IO.FileShare.Read, true, "");
    acCurDb.Insert("COORD2D", blkDb, true);
}
blkRecId = acBlkTbl["COORD2D"];
```

I don't want to have to specify the path. I want it to find it because it is in the supported search paths. So what step am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this useful [link](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/insert-external-dwg-file-as-block-using-support-file-search-path/td-p/5729434). It was for VB but I was able to adopt the principle:

```
if (!acBlkTbl.Has("COORD2D"))
{
    _AcDb.Database blkDb = new _AcDb.Database(false, true);
    string blockPath = _AcDb.HostApplicationServices.Current.FindFile("COORD2D.DWG",
                            acCurDb, _AcDb.FindFileHint.Default);
    blkDb.ReadDwgFile(blockPath, System.IO.FileShare.Read, true, "");
    acCurDb.Insert("COORD2D", blkDb, true);
}
blkRecId = acBlkTbl["COORD2D"];
```

I had to use the [`FindFile`](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=OREFNET-Autodesk_AutoCAD_DatabaseServices_HostApplicationServices_FindFile_string_Database_Autodesk_AutoCAD_DatabaseServices_FindFileHint) command.

---

### Sidenote

One of the answers [here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/objectarx/what-directories-readdwgfile-chech/td-p/317373) states:

> `AcDbDatabase::readDwgFile()` expects the filename argument to be a full path. It **does not** search along any search paths to 
>   find the file.
>
> Use `AcDbHostApplicationServices::findFile()` to 
>   find the file and get a full path before calling `readDwgFile()`.

Comment: @BouRHooD Great! Don't forget to also upvote my actual question too.